# Regular expression in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, database, oracle, database-administration

I want to fetch a string pattern in column of table. I am using a query like

```
select CALCULATION_DETAILS 
  from DS_ELEMENT_CALC_PROPERTY 
 where REGEXP_LIKE(CALCULATION_DETAILS, 'fm.get');
```

I am not able to figure out the exact regexp for my requirement.

`CALCULATION_DETAILS` is `clob` and it contains a very lengthy string of JavaScript code.
It has a syntax like `fm.get('11abc') or fm.get('11') or fm.get('ab1c') or fm.get('abc')`t.

I want to fetch the `CALCULATION_DETAILS` which has `fm.get('11abc') or fm.get('111')` means which starts with numbers inside to `fm.get()`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the following?

```
SELECT
    CALCULATION_DETAILS 
FROM 
    DS_ELEMENT_CALC_PROPERTY 
WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE(CALCULATION_DETAILS, 'fm.get\(''[0-9]+'
```

> pattern for which has one or more spaces inside to fm.get(). ex: fm.get('ab d') or fm.get('ab d ed d')

```
SELECT
    CALCULATION_DETAILS 
FROM 
    DS_ELEMENT_CALC_PROPERTY 
WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE(CALCULATION_DETAILS, 'fm.get\(''[a-zA-Z0-9] [a-zA-Z0-9 ]+''\)')
```

Comment: as i mentioned i need complete pattern which starts with numbers inside to fm.get(). ex:fm.get('123') or fm.get('23addc')

Comment: Re-read the question and understood that you want the escaping sequence for special characters in regex language and those from Oracle's SQL. I just updated my answer. Do you want to check once if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: similarly i want one more pattern for which has one or more spaces inside to fm.get(). ex: fm.get('ab d') or fm.get('ab d ed d') could you please help me out

Comment: Can you check the second query in my response? It allows the arguments to fm.get to be alphabets, numbers with spaces. If you don't want to capture those with numbers, you can remove 0-9 from that regex.

Comment: the second query is bringing all records which does not have space in fm.get() as well

Comment: Sorry, edited to expect atleast one space in between. you can tweak it if you want to accept spaces at the beginning or towards end.

Comment: I see that you logged http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529026/regular-expression-in-oracle-for-search-space. didn't the above one work?

Comment: sorry, the one you provided is not working.it fetched none of the records.. even though there are few records matches the criteria.

Comment: can you provide a couple of examples that should have matched but didnt? or if you got answer already, you can ignore this...